# Is there any telerik control to delete these file from SQL DB?

Tags: c#, sql, telerik

I am working on a web Project using ASP.NET,C# and Telerik control.
I am using Telerik control telerik:RadAsyncUpload to upload multipe files
After clicking submit button I am saving that files in Database in bytes format.
When I want to Update this record...I am fetching that files from database and showing links for that file.
So that when I will click on link, file will get downloaded.

Is there any telerik control to delete these file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the File Explorer Control from Telerik, some samples you can find here:
[File Explorer](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Also you can use a custom "File Content Provider" for the communication with your database, a sample implementation you find here: [Custom File Content Provider](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/server-sideapi/dbfilebrowsercontentprovider/defaultcs.aspx) and here you will find the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/fileexplorer/server-side-programming/use-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider).

Another way would be to create a button (next to your download link) which fire your delete method :-), maybe simpler if you only need to delete these files.